# If function has two array parameters how to return the second one

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
function isVow(a) {
  console.log(a);
}

isVow([1232, 1, 342], [3, 2, 4]);

// console output [1232, 1, 342]
```

How can I display `[3, 2, 4]`to the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use function's arguments like below

```
function isVow() {
  console.log('arguments[0]' , arguments[0]);
  console.log('arguments[1]' , arguments[1]);
}

isVow([1232, 1, 342], [3, 2, 4]);
```

You get output like this

```
arguments[0] [1232, 1, 342]
arguments[1] [3, 2, 4]
```

cheers....

Comment: i get undefined in arguments[1]

Answer (score 2):

You need 2nd parameter b

```
function isVow(a,b) {
  console.log(b);
}

isVow([1232, 1, 342], [3, 2, 4]);
```

**Edit**

You can try this with 1 parameter:

```
function isVow(a) {
  console.log(a[1]);
}

isVow([[1232, 1, 342], [3, 2, 4]]);
```

Comment: i cant add 2nd parameter cause i have only 1 input parameter if i do like your solution i get undefined; p.s. codewars task

Comment: Glad i could help. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add to function second param `b`

```
function func(a,b){
console.log(a,b);
}

isVow([1232, 1, 342], [3, 2,4]);
```

Comment: i cant add 2nd parameter cause i have only 1 input parameter if i do like your solution i get undefined; p.s. codewars task

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
function func(){
    if(arguments.length > 1) {
        console.log(arguments[1]);
    }
}
```

Read more about [arguments object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments)

Comment: i get undefined in arguments[1]

Comment: Are you passing two arguments? Two arrays? `func([1232, 1, 342], [3, 2, 4])`

Comment: @Jakib Jankowski i have to input arrays like a perimeters of function, i need check this arrays for smth and return if true one of them but 2nd perimeter all time undefined.